# URL rewriting with folder-like style

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I am creating a website and i want to have folder-like urls like this:

for http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=page&p1=paramter&p2=paramter2&p3=parameter3

I want: http://www.domain.com/page/parameter/parameter2/parameter3

So, I have done a code like this:

```
#Hide folder's content from users
Options All -Indexes

#Url rewriting
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /IXF/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&p1=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&=p3=$4 [QSA,L]
```

And it's working good! But the only problem is I have a css file in /css/main.css and the rewriting is trying to load the page "css" and send parameter1=main.css. How could I fix this problem?

I searched on internet but I found nothing. And I have the impression that every url rewriting problems are differents...
Anyway, if you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember: **every** *RewriteCond* works for the **very first** *RewriteRule*. So that, if file exists, it it's ignored except the stylesheet's URL is */style.css*.

Solution: repeat *RewriteCond* blocks for each *RewriteRule* or (what I do recommend) move routing to the application. Relying on htaccess is not portable and moving to the another httpd (for example nginx) will require more work that it should.

Comment: Thank! It work for css/main.css but not when I'm trying /page/paramter

Comment: Just use an absolute URLs.

Comment: Yes... It's what I figured out. It will be enough! Thanks